# Width of border bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation menu using bootstrap now I want to add border-bottom to the active link, unfortunately, the width of border-bottom is greater than the width of the text itself.

Here is codepen [live demo](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/LYxxygW)

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-link {
  padding: 20px;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active .nav-link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

expected result:

[image]

what do I need to to get what I want?

Comment: this is because you space the buttons apart with a padding which is the inner border. If you want to space them without spacing the border aswell, use margin which is the outer border.

Comment: I know that but I need that padding though m that is why asked is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tacoshy mentioned, using margin instead of padding will put the spacing outside of the border.

You can also add padding to the `.nav-item` element that surrounds the `.nav-link`.

What it looks like you're trying to do is put 20px of spacing on all sides. If you move that 20px to the left and right padding of the surrounding `.nav-item` element, and set the left and right padding of `.nav-link` to 0, then the border will only be the length of the text. You can then add some of the vertical spacing to inside the `.nav-link` element and the remaining spacing to the top and bottom padding of the `.nav-item` element.

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item {
  /* add 10px to top and bottom padding, add 20px to left and right padding */
  padding: 10px 20px; 
}

/* added .nav-item to selector in order to properly override bootstrap padding */
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
  /* add 10px top and bottom padding, 0 left and right padding */
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active .nav-link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```